# Problem with if-statement used at Table-returned-function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have simplified my function to the following:

```
create function [dbo].[UserSuperTeams](@ProjectId int) 
returns table 
as 
return 
   if @ProjectId=0
   begin 
      select TeamId from TblTeam t 
        union
      select 0 as TeamId
   end
   else
   begin
      select t.TeamId from TblTeam t
        union
      select 1 as TeamId
   end;
go
```

I cannot make it work.. It seems I have some syntax errors, but I cannot figure out how to make it work.. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to use t-sql code in the function, you need to define the table in the 'returns' section, then populate it with insert statements:

```
create function [dbo].[UserSuperTeams](@ProjectId int) 
  returns @results table (
    TeamId int
  ) as begin

  if @ProjectId=0 begin       
    insert @results (TeamId)
      select TeamId from TblTeam t
      union      
      select 0 as TeamId   
  end   
  else begin
    insert @results (TeamId)
      select t.TeamId from TblTeam t
      union      
      select 1 as TeamId   
end;

return
end
```

Comment: this will be parsed, but when executed, I get an error:
"The last statement included within a function must be a return statement"

Comment: There's also an "end" missing. Just add: "return; end" to the end of what Ray has given

Comment: I've updated Ray's answer, just to add the return statement in

Comment: oops - should check my own syntax :(

Comment: For me, this is very slow when used as subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare the table with a temporary name and a schema in the function declaration, then insert into it in the function:

```
create function [dbo].[UserSuperTeams](@ProjectId int) 
returns @mytable table (TeamID int)  
as 
...
```

and then something like:

```
INSERT INTO @mytable 
select t.TeamId from TblTeam t
    union
select 1 as TeamId
```

This works especially well for functions that insert several rows into the table.

Alternatively, if you only wish to return the results of a single `SELECT`, you can use an inline return:

```
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        select t.TeamId from TblTeam t
            union
        select 1 as TeamId
    )
END
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy said, or if it really is very like your simplified example you can do:

```
create function [dbo].[UserSuperTeams](@ProjectId int) 
returns table 
as 
return (select TeamId from TblTeam t 
        union
        select CASE WHEN @ProjectId = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as TeamId
       )
go
```

(i.e. you may not have to define the table var/schema)

Comment: my example was really simplified and this solution cannot be applied :(

Comment: Ah ok. In which case, +1 to @Jeremy's solution. I'll leave my answer as it does highlight the potential use of an alternative dependent on the exact scenario

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me :

```html
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [dbo].[test] 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TEST] 
(
 @ACTIVEONLY bit
)
RETURNS @TST TABLE (column1 char)
AS
BEGIN
 IF @ACTIVEONLY = 1
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @TST(column1) VALUES('A')
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @TST(column1) VALUES('B')
 END
 RETURN
END
GO

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TEST](1)
GO

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TEST](0)
GO
```